# How can I write KSQL queries in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, ksqldb

Could you provide me with a code sample in node js that runs KSQL queries on Kafka ?
F.e. I would like to create **and** then retrieve a simple table.

Comment: till there is not library for node.js?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik there's no library that would do that for you. Did you look at using the REST api for this?

https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/api.html

Comment: Still there is not library for node.js?

Comment: So far there's only Java client library available.
Official list: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-clients/